# How do I catch form data in my controller using a class object and not the traditional getData() Method in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a search form in which I use to search my database to produce some result.

using the below in a my forms directory as a form class I generate the form.

```
   $builder->add(
            'startDate',
            DateType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'start date',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                    new Constraints\DateTime(),
                ],
            ]
        );
```

in my controller I already have retrieved the data using the getData() method

```
 $form = $this->createForm(testForm::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
          
            $start = date_format($form->get('start')->getData(), 'Y-m-d');
```

At the moment I want to get this data using a class object

e.g like this

```
   $form = $this->createForm(testForm::class, $classobject);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
```

where I would use the class object to retrieve the posted data from the form class "testForm"

how have I tried to solve this on my own?

I tried reading tutorials on this concept e.g as below

```
https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/
```

**note : this is a learning curve for me, I do not really grasp this concept**

Please, constructive responses would be well appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can specify the `data_class`-option as described in the last paragraph [here in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

Comment: please can expanciate using the docs and after specifying class how do I capture the data and for example echo it out. can you use the code I posted in my question @dbrumann

Comment: and what would be the data class here?  $classobject ?? @dbrumann

Comment: Maybe I can see the source of some of your confusion.  The docs are always the place to start when learning.  Stay away from random tutorials.  The [example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms) shows how to process a task object.  The example shows $task = $form->getData() for some reason but you don't need that line at all.  There are also some confusing comments about it.  Bottom line is that when you pass an object to to createForm, that object will be updated when the form is posted.  No need to do anything else.

Comment: @Cerad when I do this "$form = $this->createForm(testForm::class, $wole);"  I get the error "Notice: Undefined variable: wole", obviously that variable was not created prior to that time

Comment: what should I be doing here

Comment: You should be reading the link I gave you and working through the Task example.

Comment: I thought you said the link has a bit of incorrect information?

Comment: The linked example is fine.  It works with and without the getData statement.

Comment: did exactly as you said, I came up with this error Neither the property "startDate" nor one of the methods "getStartDate()", "startDate()", "isStartDate()", "hasStartDate()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class.   @Cerad

Comment: of course inplace of task iv replaced it with the required entity

Comment: Have you considered adding a getStartDate() method to your entity?  Sort of like the way the Task entity has a getDueDate().

Comment: hi thanks, I added that method respectively for both start and end dates now im stuck at this point "Could not determine access type for property "startDate" in class".  for this I tried. /**
 * @var \DateTIme
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="period", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */.    this is because period is the column name that holds the date in the database. im stuck here

Comment: I sorted that part out by declaring set methods, this is where im stuck as at now " Expected argument of type "string", "object" given at property path "startDate"

Answer (score 0):

$form->getData() will return the object populated with the submited data. By default the Form Component returns an array, but if you pass an object as the second arg to createForm or set data_class option then you will get the object back.